# how to find the sum of the given values of a document named v in this given below mongodb collection named l5p1s1

Tags: mongodb

Given below is the command to seperate out the specific values whose sum of v needs to be found

```
db.l5p1s1.find({$and : [{x : {$lte : 1}} , {y:{$lte : 1}}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e798bdc2e247231115a8717"), "x" : 0, "y" : 0, "v" : 0.1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e798bdc2e247231115a8718"), "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "v" : 0.04 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e798c092e247231115a871a"), "x" : 1, "y" : 0, "v" : 0.08 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e798c092e247231115a871b"), "x" : 1, "y" : 1, "v" : 0.2 }
```

Comment: Sum of v for all or group based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    db.l5p1s1.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [{ x: { $lte: 1 } }, { y: { $lte: 1 } }]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {},
            sum: { $sum: '$v' }
        }
    }
])
```